# max object size in GIT HUB

Tags: object, size, max

I am trying to push my EAR into GIT repo on Blue mix Dev Ops. 
I tried force push as well. Git push fails with below error

> Counting objects: 4, done.
>
> Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>
> Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
>
> Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 17.35 MiB | 48.00 KiB/s, done.
>
> Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
>
> error: unpack failed: error Object too large (108,624,080 bytes), rejecting the pack. Max object size limit is 104,857,600 bytes.
>
> To https://hub.jazz.net/git/poem/InspectionsPOEM
>    ! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://hub.jazz.net/git/poem/InspectionsPOEM'

Please let me know how to set the max limit, size for the file in GIT and who has the access to do it

Thanks
Mathangi